# Property subspace must include the 0 vector and non empty subspace relation.

Tags: linear-algebra

One of the properties of a subspace is the fact that the 0 vector must be in the subspace,
im reading the book "Linear algebra done right" and it mentions that this condition could be replaced with the condition that the subspace is non empty, but i cant understand why.

For example, the subset U = {x1, 3} is non empty but it does not contain the vector 0. So how can the non empty condition replace the 0 vector condition? i think this is where im stuck.

Comment: Because if the subspace is non-empty, we can take the additive identity $0$ from the underlying field and multiply it by some element $x$ in your vector space to obtain $0 \cdot x = 0$. Here, the $\cdot$ is the scalar multiplication and it equals $0$ by an almost immediate consequence of the vector space axioms. Since the subspace is closed under scalar multiplication, this implies that the zero vector $0$ is in our subspace.

Comment: I edited my question, thank you.

Comment: $U$ is not a subspace. Namely, it is not closed under vector addition.

Comment: Ok i think i understand now, the non empty condition can replace the 0 vector condition given that the other two conditions apply.

Comment: Yes. The author is only saying that the condition of having a zero vector can be replaced with non-emptiness of the subset. We still need the other axioms of a subspace to hold. For example, closure under addition and scalar multiplication.